# managing my sessions

Tags: php, session, authentication, session-variables

I'm creating session variables with every login it's $_SESSION['usr'] & $_SESSION['psw']. When I log out I'm destroying them with this code:

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
if(count($_SESSION) == 0)
{
$_SESSION=array();
session_destroy();
}
header("Location:home.php");
?>
```

What I'm trying to do is to restricted some of the pages only for logged in users so I tried to use this little piece of code:

```
<?php if(!$_SESSION['usr']){header('Location:home.php');} ?>
```

I don't understand why it's not working, because it's making total sense but it doesn't anyone any idea why? Thank you for all your help...

Comment: You have asked 24 questions, but you have accepted answers on only 52% of those. This is frowned upon on this site — people are trying to help you and you're just disregarding their work.

Comment: do `session_start(); var_dump($_SESSION);` and see if there is any key with 'usr' in it

Comment: This is the output of var_dump: array(0) { }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be trying to destroy the session twice.

It should be:

```
<?php
  session_start();   
  $_SESSION = array();
  //Session Cookie
  if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
      $params = session_get_cookie_params();
      setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
      );
  }
  session_destroy();
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php

There's no need to check if something's set.
And the check should probably be:

```
<?php if(!isset($_SESSION['usr'])) {
   //header() - see below
} ?>
```

And the Location needs to be an absolute url (e.g. `http://www.mydomain.com/home.php`)